# Linux - (Intermediate)signal handlers?

Tags: linux, signals

I am working on linux.

I wish to execute a function(cleaning stuff & flsuhing data) when my application crashes(SIGSEGV or other signals). I am aware of doing this by overwriting signals but I want to keep the original signal handling intact.

I wish to execute one function just after signal occurs and a signal handler is called. Is there a way i can do this?

Comment: Please be more specific. Exactly which signals are you trying to handle, and which default behavior do you want to preserve?

Comment: Currently i have not decided on which signals to handle. Beforehand, i wanted to check if at all some support is available for my need. Like if i recieve a SIGSEGV, i would like to execute a function cleanup() and then the application should terminate like it is terminating because of SIGSEGV

Comment: You seem to be fixated on sigsegv.  Aside from some very specific circumstances this is rarely the right thing to do.  If this is really your concern your time would be better spent insuring you don't segfault to begin with.  Otherwise, in general you can reset the signal disposition from within a handler easily enough but calling a function that does non-trivial things (like saving data) from w/i a handler is not a great idea.

Comment: From C99 standard 7.14.1.1 p3: *If and when the function returns, if the value of sig is SIGFPE, SIGILL, SIGSEGV, or any other implementation-defined value corresponding to a computational exception, the behavior is undefined; otherwise the program will resume execution at the point it was interrupted.*